# Integrate appium to jmeter for performance testing?

Tags: java, automation, jmeter, appium

I could see from here (http://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/WebDriverSampler/) that Webdriver can be used with JMeter to perform the performance testing for web application.
Similarly is there a way (some plugin) where we can add the remote web driver and use appium for mobile web performance testing on real device itself ?
If thats not the way, can anyone suggest me what is the best way to achieve it (Mobile Web Performance Testing on real device i.e : using Beanshell in Jmeter to execute Java code through appium ..).

Answer (score 0):

WebDriver Sampler is designed to fill in JMeter gaps as JMeter:

- doesn't actually "render" the page
- doesn't execute client-side Javascript

So when main load is generated by JMeter's [HTTP Request](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) samplers and you want to check rendering speed you may add a separate [Thread Group](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Thread_Group) which will execute the WebDriver Sampler. WebDriver is not replacement to JMeter HTTP Request sampler, it's addition which should be run with a single thread.

---

For mobile testing side of thins, mobile applications usually have only one user so it doesn't make any sense to do performance testing of mobile application itself. However when mobile application is hybrid, i.e. it displays data from backend server or database - you may want to load test that backend simulating high number of mobile devices concurrently working with it. In order to do it:

- [Record your mobile device traffic](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/207420545-BlazeMeter-Recorder-Mobile-Recorder-)
- Perform correlation and parametrization if required
- [Add users](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/build-web-test-plan.html#adding_users)
- Run your test and analyze results